# Delete adjacent cells if duplicate?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a VBA macro that searches through column A and every time it finds 2 cells in that column that are the same (and adjacent!) to delete one of the 2 and shift up. I want it to stay in column A, and every time a duplicate came up that was adjacent to delete it.
Pretty much I have an excel sheet that alternates information like so:

A

B

A

B

But I often hit snags like this

A

B

A

B

B

A

Those 2 B's are what I want it to automatically clear and shift cells up on, but I am unsure how to go about it.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: I solved my own question. The answer is down below but here it is again to help others who may have come across the issue as I have.

Nevermind folks. I got this one. I recorded a macro that uses filters and a simple formula. In column B I put this in: =IF(a1=a2,"STOP","") Then I dragged it down to copy it. Then I filtered column B to show only "STOP" cells. Then I cleared out those cells. Then I unfiltered column B to show all. Then I went to Home>Find and Select>Special>Select Blanks Then I deleted and shifted cells up the selected blanks. Then I re dragged the B column formula down to make a working loop for my recorded macro. Heres what the recording ended up looking like:

```
Sub DUPES()

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[1]C[-1],""DLT"","""")"
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("J2:J1000").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$500").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("I11:J11").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A11").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$500").AutoFilter Field:=10
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-42
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("J2:J1000").Select

Range("I2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried manually recording a macro to remove duplicates while telling it to exit sub when it reached a "different" variable.

Comment: If sel.Offset(i).Value = prev Then    
 sel.Offset(i).EntireRow.Delete

I also tried messing with offsets, but, I am really not good at making this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind folks. I got this one. I recorded a macro that uses filters and a simple formula.
In column B I put this in:
    =IF(a1=a2,"STOP","")
Then I dragged it down to copy it.
Then I filtered column B to show only "STOP" cells.
Then I cleared out those cells. 
Then I unfiltered column B to show all.
Then I went to Home>Find and Select>Special>Select Blanks
Then I deleted and shifted cells up the selected blanks.
Then I re dragged the B column formula down to make a working loop for my recorded macro.
Heres what the recording ended up looking like:

```
Sub DUPES()

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=R[1]C[-1],""DLT"","""")"
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("J2:J1000").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$500").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("I11:J11").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A11").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$500").AutoFilter Field:=10
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-42
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("J2:J1000").Select

Range("I2").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub removedup
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$8").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
end sub
```

There is a remove duplicate button in excel 2007/10/13 in the ribbon - but as you want vba this assumes that you have column headers in a1 and b1

Comment: Yeah I knew about that button. Sorry I wasnt very clear but I wanted it to stay in column A, and every time a duplicate came up that was adjacent to delete it. Ill edit my OP to reflect this.

Comment: are there more than 2 variables in column A as its dummy data above?

Comment: Yes and No. Using the Dummy above, my excel sheet has many different possibilities for A, but B is always the same.